# Generate XML from java Properties in a predefined XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I need to generate an XML file for some key value pairs. I know this is basic but i am looking for a simple way to do it. 
This is how i want my XML to be generated. I have Name value pairs as properties.

```
    <ConfigInfo>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <Value>Value1</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Name2</Name>
      <Value>Value2</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Name3</Name>
      <Value>Value3</Value>
    </Attribute>
    </ConfigInfo>
```

Is there a way to do this without using JAXB ?

Comment: Use, just use the [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/). What's the problem you're having? Please show some effort you have made.

Comment: I think JAXB is the easiest way.

Comment: The easiest way, as opposed to the optimal way, is the one involving the tools and knowledge you already have, most likely. I think an ant script might well be the easiest, but this can be accomplished in many, many different ways so maybe throw us some preferences or constraints of yours here.

Comment: @all Thanks a lot for your time. I was able to generate XML by using Java StAX Iterator API. I am validating the generated XML with XSD which i already have. 

[write XML file in Java using Java StAX Iterator API](http://www.journaldev.com/892/how-to-write-xml-file-in-java-using-java-stax-api)